# Yii2 - how to register bootstrap css correctly?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, yii2

I'm trying to register both bootstrap css and my own css file. This is the code that is being used:

```
$this->registerCssFile('https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
$this->registerCssFile('css/style.css', ['rel' => 'stylesheet', 'type' => 'text/css']);
```

When I do so, some declarations from "css/style.css" are not working. Trying to comment out the registration of the bootstrap corrects the situation.

I'm quite new to Yii. Please advise me on how to achieve my goal? I'd like both to use the advantages of the bootstrap css and also utilize my own css rules.

Comment: is it any particular page where you want to load bootstrap 4 or you are using it globally for all the site. and please add your custom css classes that you are using are you overrirding the default bootstrap classes?

Comment: It looks like some conflict between bootstrap and your styles -  you should look into developer tools and see whats happening here. Most likely bootstrap overrides some of your styles by using a more precise selector.

Comment: This is my CSS: https://pastebin.com/cHam7ThD
I really do not understand, what exactly here can be overridden...